# Name and origin of this alternative rock drumbeat

Tags: rhythm, drums, rock-n-roll

Does anyone know the name and origin of this drumbeat? It's widely used in alternative rock, and although I think people would tend to describe it as "funky," it isn't a textbook funk beat as far as I know.

Here is a basic sketch:

[image]

This is just the kick and snare pattern; there are a few common variations.

Here is a slow example:

And a faster one:

Answer (score 5):

It's been in every rock song since the late 60s. Went out of favour in the 80s then came back with a vengeance with Madchester and Brit Pop, from 89 or so right through the 90s.
In the version as scored in your OP, I think I must have played that in my first ever gig on drums… in 1973 ;)

This is the earliest one that springs to mind. Mountain, Long Red, live at Woodstock in 1969. The groove is the same, but the kick/snare is used slightly differently. Played here by Norman D. Smart, who was replaced afterwards by Corky Laing.
This is reckoned to be one of the most sampled recordings ever made.
https://www.whosampled.com/Mountain/Long-Red/sampled/ 764 times

Other songs from the same gig show signs of it, but not as a full-on riff in its own right.

As a strictly funk riff, it was used by James Brown in Funky Drummer, 1970 - another riff that's been sampled to death since. I don't know if anything has been resampled more than this one…
https://www.whosampled.com/James-Brown/Funky-Drummer/ 1640 times
So, whilst I don't think it's the origin by a long way, it's definitely the most famous.

Full track

Looped famous riff

In this form, you can definitely refer to it as the Funky Drummer riff.

From comments, I'd forgotten The Winstons, Amen Brother from 69 - but again this is the funk version, not the rock version in the OP.

---

I realised it's also very slightly apparent in Buffalo Springfield's For What it's Worth, from 1967 - though you kind of have to 'back recognise' it, already knowing what you're looking for.

Comment: These all seem like loose matches, especially the Buffalo Springfield one, unless I'm not listening to the right part of the song.  Regardless, I think the amen break from The Winstons' "Amen Brother" (1969) is worth a mention.

Comment: Yeah, I'd forgotten that one, but again, the Amen Brother riff is the funk version, not the rock version as in the OP.